# Inserting into sql from node.js javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, visual-studio-2017

Can someone help me get a node.js javascript app to communicate with a sql server running on /localhost?

Here's a step-by-step of what I've done and where I'm stuck. 
(I'm using visual studio, node.js, mssql, and sql server express 2016)

[I created a new SQL Server Database project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6OV8.png)

[Added a new table called Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiRcF.png)

[Set up Table1 to have 2 columns, ID and dataText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwLbW.png)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [DataText] TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

[Added a new Login (SQL Server)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzlD3.png)

[set the new login to be javaLogin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1YFk.png)

```
CREATE LOGIN javaLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'internetDisplayPsswd'
```

[Closed the SQL project and created a new blank node.js Javascript project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q9WG.png)

[Installed npm mssql package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMXhD.png)

Ran the following code:

```
const sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
    user: 'javaLogin',
    password: 'internetDisplayPsswd',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'Table1'
};

async () => {
    try {
        const pool = await sql.connect(config);
        const result = await sql.query('INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (Bear)');
        console.dir(result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.dir(err);
    }
};
console.log('Hello world');
```

I get no errors or indication of what's wrong, but it doesn't insert anything into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `async` function is defined but never called. Wrap it in parentheses and call it.

```
(async () => {
    ...
})();
```

Comment: { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
    at Connection.tedious.once.err